# mysql php alphabetical listing with index-letters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database (plattenkiste) with bandnames

```
id | kuenstler
1 | Aerosmith
2 | Beck
3 | Metallica
4 | Slayer
5 | Zappa, Frank
```

Now i want an output in alphabetical Order with directlinks and index-letters, showing only the index-letters with bandnames.

Like

```
Directlinks: A|B|M|S|Z


A
Aerosmith
B
Beck
M
Metallica
S
Slayer
Z
Zappa, Frank
```

I have a "quick and dirty" code that does what i want:

```
$abc = "0123456789AÄBCDEFGHIJKLMNOÖPQRSTUÜVWXYZ";

for($i=0; $i<strlen($abc); $i++){
   $char = substr($abc, $i, 1);
   $query = "SELECT kuenstler FROM plattenkiste WHERE kuenstler LIKE '$char%'";
   $ergebnis = $mysqli->query($query);
   $num = $ergebnis->num_rows;
   if ($num != 0){
   echo "<a href='#$char'>$char</a> | ";
   }}

for($i=0; $i<strlen($abc); $i++){
   $char = substr($abc, $i, 1);
   $query = "SELECT kuenstler FROM plattenkiste WHERE kuenstler LIKE '$char%'";
   $ergebnis = $mysqli->query($query);
   $num = $ergebnis->num_rows;
   if ($num != 0){

   echo "<h4 id='$char'>$char</h4>";

 while($row = $ergebnis->fetch_object()){
    echo $row->kuenstler . '<br />';
        } 
   }
}
```

Is there a shorter, more clean way to get this done?

Comment: HI kali, although this is not my specialty I will give you a few pointers on asking this question on stack overflow. Since this site is primarily english and it appears your english is very good I would consider creating a separate code sample that the variable names etc.. are in english, this may increase the number of people willing to help you out. Then all you would need to do is convert it back once you have received some help.

Comment: Also, the question appears to be of the type that a lot of SO users are not willing to help with because it appears that you are asking someone to work out your problem for you. I would rethink the way you ask this question and possibly attempt to at the very least let us know what you concern for not wanting to use this version of your code and what exactly you are trying to achieve. Sometimes there is a fine line between what users will perceive as you asking us to solve your problems or having a legitimate well asked question that people will help you out with.

Comment: @EricB That makes sense, i will keep this in mind for further questions. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: No problem, I didn't downvote it, it appears someone else did, I just figured since some people downvote and don't give a reason I would try to expand on why I thought it was downvoted. I appreciate the response, looks like you did get an answer that helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have MySQL do much of the grunt for you, by both sorting the results and (for the initial list) providing only the initial characters.  Then you merely need have PHP loop over the resultsets and output the necessary HTML (for the second list, adding a header whenever it encounters a new initial character).

If your `plattenkiste.kuenstler` column has a case sensitive collation then you may wish to explicitly specify a case insensitive collation in the `ORDER BY` clauses.

```
$query = 'SELECT   DISTINCT UCASE(LEFT(kuenstler, 1)) AS char
          FROM     plattenkiste
          ORDER BY kuenstler';
$ergebnis = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($ergebnis) {
  while ($row = $ergebnis->fetch_object()) {
    $char = htmlentities($row->char);
    echo "<a href='#$char'>$char</a> | ";
  }
}


$query = 'SELECT kuenstler FROM plattenkiste ORDER BY kuenstler';
$ergebnis = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($ergebnis) {
  $row = $ergebnis->fetch_object();
  while ($row) {
    $c = $row->kuenstler[0];
    $char = htmlentities(strtoupper($c));

    echo "<h4 id='$char'>$char</h4>";
    do {
      echo htmlentities($row->kuenstler), '<br />';
    } while ($row = $ergebnis->fetch_object() and $row->kuenstler[0] == $c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is the perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do things like this before as well. The easiest option is to just loop through your results and build a series of arrays...

```
$artists = $mysqli->query(
    'SELECT kuenstler FROM Lattenkiste ORDER BY kuenstler ASC'
);

$letters = array();

// get the results and sort them into arrays
while($artist = $artists->fetch_object()) {
    // ge the first letter
    $firstLetter = strtoupper($artist->kuenstler{0});

    // if we don't have a key for it, make it
    if (!isset($letters[$firstLetter])) {
        $letters[$firstLetter] = array();
    }

    $letters[$firstLetter] = $artist->kuenstler;
}


// output the headings
echo '<ul class="directlinks">';

foreach (array_keys($letters) as $letter) {
    echo '<li><a href="#' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';

// now output each set of letters
foreach (array_keys($letters) as $letter) {
    echo '<h4 id="' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</h4>';
    echo '<ul class="artists">';

    foreach ($letters[$letter] as $kuenstler) {
        echo '<li>' . $kuenstler . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```